# Swift Animate Mask Transition

Tags: swift, uikit

How can you animate a mask moving down X pixels?

I have a circular mask applied to a black view that creates a spotlight effect. I want to animate the mask transitioning down 100 pixels, but using `UIView.animate { mask.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(.init(), 0, 100, 0) }` instantly moves it instead of animating the transition.

Here's the mask code:

```
    private lazy var mask: CAShapeLayer = {
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 40, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2.0 * .pi, clockwise: false)
        path.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.frame.size))

        mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mask.path = path
        mask.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        return mask
    }()

overlayView.layer.mask = mask
```

How would you animate this moving down 100 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Core animation block. CALayer animation is not supported by UIView animation block. To animate `mask` property we use the `path` key.

```
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
anim.toValue = createPath(center: .init(x: 100, y: 100))
anim.duration = 1
anim.fillMode = .forwards
anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
mask.add(anim, forKey: anim.keyPath)
```

Comment: Hm. This animates the entire view moving down instead of just the mask

Answer (score 0):

To get the spotlight effect, you'll want to create paths that modify the arc shape and animate between them.

```
func spotlightPath(arcCenter: CGPoint) -> CGPath {
    let path = CGMutablePath()

    // move the spotlight
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arcCenter.x, y: arcCenter.y), radius: 40, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2.0 * .pi, clockwise: false)

    path.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.frame.size))

    return path
}

let startPath = spotlightPath(arcCenter: .zero)
```

And then later

```
let endPath = spotlightPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 100))

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.duration = 1
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.fillMode = .forwards
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
animation.toValue = endPath

mask.add(animation, forKey: "path")
```